# Laravel Eloquent ORM - Return objects having objects that also belong to a third object

Tags: php, model, controller, laravel, eloquent

First things first, I'm starting with php and MVC frameworks, I'm still not really good at this, I also couldn't do a lot of research on the problem because I don't really know how to translate this into a google search.

And thats also why my question title is so funny

Ok, so lets say I have three models: Post, Commenter and Comment

The comments belong both to the posts and the commenters, so I have this code in my models, its all very simple

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function comments() {
        return $this->has_many('Comment');
    }
}
```

...

```
class Commenter extends Eloquent {

    public function comments () {
        return $this->has_many('Comment');
    }
}
```

...

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    public function commenter () { 
        return $this->belongsTo('Commenter');
    }

    public function post () {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
}
```

And then I want a query to list commenters ONLY IF they have comments on a given post

I need to go through the commenters list and then find whoever has comments belonging to that one post. (I don't really need to worry about being optimal since its an small experimental project with a small database)

I have no Idea how to pass this on to a view using a controller, `Commenter::has('comments')` will display anyone that has a comment anywhere, but I think thats the starting point. I couldnt really find an answer in the documentation also.

Please let me know if I havent made my question clear enough

Comment: Please provide us your `Commenter` class.

Comment: Edited with all the classes now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized there wouldnt be a method as simple as I wanted, so I decided to go for a new Many to Many relationship...

I added

```
public function posts () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
}
```

and

```
public function commenters () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Commenter');
}
```

and now I can simply use a

```
->with ('commenters', Post::find($post_id)->commenters()->get())
```

in my controller to find my list of commenters

Thanks for the help, everybody who answered.

Answer (score 2):

Having

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    public function commenter () { 
        return $this->belongsTo('Commenter');
    }

    public function post () {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
}

class Commenter extends Eloquent {

    public function comments () {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }

}

class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function comments () { 
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }

}
```

You can

```
$post = Post::find($givenPostID);

View::make('posts.comments.listCommenters')
  ->with('commenters', $post->comments()->groupBy('commenter_id')->get(['commenter_id']));
```

And in the View

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
  Author: <strong>{{$comment->commenter->name}}</strong>
@endforeach
```

Or you can create a new property

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function getCommentersAttribute()
    {
        $comments = $this->comments;

        foreach($this->comments as $comment)
        {
           /// do whatever you need to grab your list of commenters        
        }

        return $yourListOfCommenters
    }

}
```

And then you just refer to it anywhere you need:

```
$post->commenters
```

Comment: But if I do this it will list the same author twice, if theres more than one comment belonging to him. I need to go through the list of commenters first and find whoever has comments belonging to that specific post

Comment: You're right, but to solve that I just added a groupBy above. I'm just giving you some ideas, not really solving your problem, if you think you need to go through the list of comments and then get all commenters, you might need to write some more code, a query to do that for you or a create a new method on your model to get that list of commenters.

Comment: The groupBy method might be actually helpful, thanks for the idea, but I still dont know if it's gonna do it for me. What would I have to do in order to create this new method?

Comment: Just edited to add the property. To create a method you just have to remove get*Attribute from the method name.